# jQuery is not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to populate my HTML with jQuery from a JSON file I load with a getJSON call. Unfortunately, none of my jQuery seems to be working.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Lab 4</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="lab4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="song-template">
      <a id="site" href="#"><img id="coverart" src="images/noalbum.png"/></a>
      <h1 id="title"></h1>
      <h2 id="artist"></h2>
      <h2 id="album"></h2>
      <p id="date"></p>
      <p id="genre"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some of my JSON file, in a subdirectory called resources:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Short Skirt, Long Jacket",
        "artist" : "Cake",
        "album" : "Comfort Eagle",
        "genre" : "Rock",
        "year" : 2001,
        "albumCoverURL" : "images/ComfortEagle.jpg",
        "bandWebsiteURL" : "http://www.cakemusic.com"
    }
]
```

And my JavaScript:

```
function updateHTML(result) 
{
    var templateNode = $("#song-template").clone(true);
    $("#song-template").remove();

    $.each(result, function(key, song)
    {
        var songNode = templateNode.clone(true);
        songNode.children("#site").href(song.bandWebsiteURL);
        songNode.children("#coverart").src(song.albumCoverURL);
        songNode.children("#title").text(song.name);
        songNode.children("#artist").text(song.artist);
        songNode.children("#album").text(song.album);
        songNode.children("#date").text(song.year);
        songNode.children("#genre").text(song.genre);
        $("body").append(songNode);
    });
}

function loadJSON() 
{
    var result = $.getJSON("resources/lab4.json");
    updateHTML(result)
}

$("#site").click(function() 
{
    loadJSON();
});
```

The issues so far are that:
1. My click listener on the site id doesn't work at all. I have also tried using coverart, and no dice.
2. When I explicitly call loadJSON(); and I walk through updateHTML in the debugger neither my clone or remove does anything, and my .each is just ignored.
If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to all this jquery and javascript stuff and don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: 1st things 1st : you need to setup your click listener in a `$('document').ready' statement if you don't already do it.

Comment: might make sense to use JS templating here. either underscore.js or Handlebars templates

Answer (score 5):

Problem is in your `loadJSON()` method. getJSON doesn't return result of the call. Try this

```
function loadJSON() 
{
  $.getJSON("resources/lab4.json", updateHTML);
}
```

Also you should bind the event when DOM is prepared.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#site").click(function() 
{
    loadJSON();
});
}})
```

Comment: That helped - now clicking on the image does execute the function and it does remove that node but my .each still won't do anything. Any idea for that?

Comment: Add `debugger;` inside `updateHTML` method and open console and try clicking the button. Then inspect what `result` variable contains.  Note: You're cloning the elements, injecting them creating duplicate IDs. It's better if you can create a jsfiddle which will make it easy for us to solve the error.

Comment: I don't know how to add my json file to jsfiddle. Result shows up as null in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your click listener in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
    $("#site").click(function(){
       loadJSON();
    });
});
```